# Python: How to create graph nodes and edges from csv file?

Tags: python, nodes, graph-theory, networkx

I have a csv data file where each row denotes one event. A simplified example would be,

```
  Datetime                 ColA     ColB    ColC   
  2015/07/12 08:45:34      ABC       12      
  2015/07/12 08:46:04      DCD       10     ABC 
  2015/07/12 08:46:23      XYZ       34     ABC 
  2015/07/12 08:46:56      MNO       10     XYZ
  2015/07/12 08:46:56      FGH       20
```

So, each row will be a `node` with properties denoted by values of each columns `Datetime, ColA, ColB, ColC`. Each of these nodes is connected by a relationship between `ColA` and `ColC`.

So, in this example there is an edge from row 1 to row 2 and row 3, since `ColC` of the latter rows is equal to `ColA` of the first row. Row 3 and row 4 are similarly connected by an directed edge.

Row 1 has no ColC so it is not connected to any nodes higher up, so is row 5.

How can I create a graph data structure to create this relationship in Python? They should all be ordered chronologically, and in case there are two rows with `ColA` that matches a rows `ColC`, the one closer in time is chosen.

Comment: You can use adjacency list to present graph structure. Have a look at this article. http://interactivepython.org/LpOMZ/courselib/static/pythonds/Graphs/graphintro.html#an-adjacency-list

Comment: @czheo Thank you for the suggestion. I'm stuck trying to create nodes with all the column as properties. Something beyond what the simple examples here show.

Answer (score 0):

You could build a bipartite graph with the datetime as one part and the ColA/ColC values as the other.  Then "project" the graph onto the datetime nodes - create a link between two datetimes if they both link to a ColA/ColC node.

Here is some code that shows one way to do that to create an undirected graph.  I didn't understand what the directions meant in your example.

```
import csv
import StringIO
import networkx as nx
from networkx.algorithms import bipartite

data ="""Datetime,ColA,ColB,ColC
2015/07/12 08:45:34,ABC,12,
2015/07/12 08:46:04,DCD,10,ABC
2015/07/12 08:46:23,XYZ,34,ABC
2015/07/12 08:46:56,MNO,10,XYZ
2015/07/12 08:46:56,FGH,20,"""

G = nx.Graph()
csvfile = StringIO.StringIO(data)
reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
nodes = []
for row in reader:
    nodes.append(row['Datetime'])
    G.add_node(row['Datetime'])
    if row['ColA'] != '':
        G.add_edge(row['Datetime'],row['ColA'])
    if row['ColC'] != '':
        G.add_edge(row['Datetime'],row['ColC'])
print G.edges()
B = bipartite.projected_graph(G, nodes)
print B.edges()
```

OUTPUT

```
[('2015/07/12 08:46:23', 'XYZ'), ('2015/07/12 08:46:23', 'ABC'), ('ABC', '2015/07/12 08:46:04'), ('ABC', '2015/07/12 08:45:34'), ('DCD', '2015/07/12 08:46:04'), ('FGH', '2015/07/12 08:46:56'), ('2015/07/12 08:46:56', 'XYZ'), ('2015/07/12 08:46:56', 'MNO')]
[('2015/07/12 08:46:23', '2015/07/12 08:46:04'), ('2015/07/12 08:46:23', '2015/07/12 08:46:56'), ('2015/07/12 08:46:23', '2015/07/12 08:45:34'), ('2015/07/12 08:46:04', '2015/07/12 08:45:34')]
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. Regarding what the arrows mean. This is like a parent child relationship. So, row 1 will be the parent of rows 2 and 3.

Comment: Because row 1 is before row 2 and 3 in time?  That you should be able to capture by looking at the time stamps.